# How do I strip the quotes from a string and use just the characters as a variable name?

Tags: python

So if I assigned a to a string with the character b in it, how do I get the character from the a string and use it to assign it to another value?

I tried:

```
a = "b"
a.strip("") = 2
# so that b = 2
print(b)
>> 2
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This seems like an XY problem

Comment: So I have a list with stock ticker symbols and want to access it when I iterate through the ticker symbol list. eg. tickers = ["TSLA"] -> print(tickers[0]["Adj Close"])